# How to get the same space between text and block

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some blocks with goods and there are different descriptions with different amounts of text and I need to center it. The button "add to cart" must be in one line not depends how many symbols in description I have. Not pure css solution welcomed (Just not jQuery solutions).

The solution with curtain height does not fit!

(Space must be between description and button "add to cart").

```css
.parent {
  border: medium dashed green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.child {
  align-self: stretch;
  border: medium dashed #c4c4c4;
  background-color: #fedba9;
  width: 40%;
}

.button {
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 50px;
  background-color: coral;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/test.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <img src="https://ogden_images.s3.amazonaws.com/www.observertoday.com/images/2020/08/29003327/SUNSET-579x840.jpg" alt="" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident voluptatibus repudiandae vitae eos, debitis eligendi rem voluptate atque iusto quo nam impedit quia tempore aperiam ducimus asperiores, odit molestiae nemo!
      </p>
      <div class="button">add to cart</div>
    </div>

    <div class="child">
      <img src="https://ogden_images.s3.amazonaws.com/www.observertoday.com/images/2020/08/29003327/SUNSET-579x840.jpg" alt="" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit mollitia accusamus dolorem, sint atque culpa eum aspernatur earum eaque nesciunt minima aliquid omnis, cum iure veritatis voluptatum nam distinctio eligendi. Fuga voluptatibus reiciendis,
        laudantium dignissimos harum modi voluptatum, ipsa a ad possimus cum accusamus. Ea alias ipsum laboriosam tempora sapiente, molestiae incidunt reprehenderit maiores perferendis earum. Ut dolorem suscipit at? Laboriosam corporis dolorem, est doloribus
        ullam ut accusantium, amet voluptate beatae vitae deleniti nihil consequuntur non labore, nobis ipsum? Sapiente earum praesentium, quasi voluptas doloremque distinctio. Veniam soluta perspiciatis porro! Fugit excepturi, perferendis expedita cum
        officiis autem eum, perspiciatis quisquam, vero ipsum ea. Odit animi sed nesciunt officiis impedit ex, in autem id quis, dolorum corporis eum cupiditate itaque repellat.
      </p>
      <div class="button">add to cart</div>
    </div>

    <div class="child">
      <img src="https://ogden_images.s3.amazonaws.com/www.observertoday.com/images/2020/08/29003327/SUNSET-579x840.jpg" alt="" />
      <p>2342342 23423423 23423423</p>
      <div class="button">add to cart</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <img src="https://ogden_images.s3.amazonaws.com/www.observertoday.com/images/2020/08/29003327/SUNSET-579x840.jpg" alt="" />
      <p>123123 12312</p>
      <div class="button">add to cart</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `flex` in direction `column` on your `.child` item
- Make the `p` inside grow to fill all remaining space
- Make it itself a `flex` to have text easily centered within

```css
.parent {
  border: medium dashed green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.child {
  align-self: stretch;
  border: medium dashed #c4c4c4;
  background-color: #fedba9;
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child p {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 50px;
  background-color: coral;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/test.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <img src="https://ogden_images.s3.amazonaws.com/www.observertoday.com/images/2020/08/29003327/SUNSET-579x840.jpg" alt="" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident voluptatibus repudiandae vitae eos, debitis eligendi rem voluptate atque iusto quo nam impedit quia tempore aperiam ducimus asperiores, odit molestiae nemo!
      </p>
      <div class="button">add to cart</div>
    </div>

    <div class="child">
      <img src="https://ogden_images.s3.amazonaws.com/www.observertoday.com/images/2020/08/29003327/SUNSET-579x840.jpg" alt="" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit mollitia accusamus dolorem, sint atque culpa eum aspernatur earum eaque nesciunt minima aliquid omnis, cum iure veritatis voluptatum nam distinctio eligendi. Fuga voluptatibus reiciendis,
        laudantium dignissimos harum modi voluptatum, ipsa a ad possimus cum accusamus. Ea alias ipsum laboriosam tempora sapiente, molestiae incidunt reprehenderit maiores perferendis earum. Ut dolorem suscipit at? Laboriosam corporis dolorem, est doloribus
        ullam ut accusantium, amet voluptate beatae vitae deleniti nihil consequuntur non labore, nobis ipsum? Sapiente earum praesentium, quasi voluptas doloremque distinctio. Veniam soluta perspiciatis porro! Fugit excepturi, perferendis expedita cum
        officiis autem eum, perspiciatis quisquam, vero ipsum ea. Odit animi sed nesciunt officiis impedit ex, in autem id quis, dolorum corporis eum cupiditate itaque repellat.
      </p>
      <div class="button">add to cart</div>
    </div>

    <div class="child">
      <img src="https://ogden_images.s3.amazonaws.com/www.observertoday.com/images/2020/08/29003327/SUNSET-579x840.jpg" alt="" />
      <p>2342342 23423423 23423423</p>
      <div class="button">add to cart</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <img src="https://ogden_images.s3.amazonaws.com/www.observertoday.com/images/2020/08/29003327/SUNSET-579x840.jpg" alt="" />
      <p>123123 12312</p>
      <div class="button">add to cart</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` on the `.child` element will move the elements equally apart.